# generate "create table" script from jdbc (clojure/java)

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, clojure

Does anyone know if anything is available to generate a "create table script" FROM a database through jdbc using clojure or java?

I could just fetch from the system tables or information schema, but per different database type that would be different. for instance MSSQL would have to be queries to build the create table (or view) from information schema and db2 from ibm.systables.  Was hoping maybe this problem had been solved before in the JDBC world.

For instance, i'm looking to diff the create table statements between a source database and a target database.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you can use `show create table`:

`(require '[clojure.java.jdbc :as jdbc])`

```
(defn gen-script [db table]
  (jdbc/with-connection db
    (jdbc/with-query-results rs [(str "show create table " table)]
      (get (first rs) (keyword "create table")))))
```

test:

```
(def db {:classname "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
         :subprotocol "mysql"
         :subname (str "//localhost:3306/testtest")
         :user "root"
         :password "..."})

(println (gen-script db "example"))

=> CREATE TABLE `example` (
     `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
     `age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

In other DBs you can start with this one:

```
(defn- gen-script [db table]
  (jdbc/with-connection db
    (let [conn (jdbc/connection)
          meta (.getMetaData conn)]
      (format "create table %s (\n%s\n)"
         table
         (apply str
           (interpose ",\n"
            (map (fn [x]
                   (format "  %s %s(%s)%s%s%s"
                      (:column_name x)
                      (:type_name x)
                      (:column_size x)
                      (if (not= "YES" (:is_nullable x)) " NOT NULL" "")
                      (if (= "YES" (:is_autoincrement x)) " AUTO_INCREMENT""")             
                      (if (= "YES" (:column_def x)) " DEFAULT" "")))
                 (resultset-seq (.getColumns meta nil nil table "%")))))))))
```

test:

```
(println (gen-script db "example"))

=> create table example (
     id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name VARCHAR(30),
     age INT(10)
```

)

Comment: That looks pretty good... i think what i'm going to have to do is have something specific to each DB.  Show table is brilliant but as far as i can tell only works on teradata and mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the hibernate tools project. It will generate a hibernate mapping and from it you can generate the create statements.

But, why go that way when you database can do that for you...

Comment: There is multiple databases of different types... i'm thinking of a data migration project, maybe data warehousing type.  I'm trying to abstract away the database specifics as its a multiple  database environment...  something to get to an somewhat-ansi-standard sql create statement.

Comment: Right, i'm going to query system tables, return sample result sets, then through introspection define a container for the inbound data.  I'm putting thought into what an "ETL Program" might look like in a language such as Clojure.